# How to call subclass method from superclass with protocol conformance

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, swift2, swift-protocols

I'm creating swift UI component that will provide some functionality to the UIView and UICollectionViewCell. I want to make it easy to customise. (code here are of course a simplification) In code below I will do some hard work in `layoutSubview` (I have to override `layoutSubviews` for each custom class because in extension we can't override class methods) and then call the `add` method with default implementation that should be easy to change its behaviour if needed.

Problem is that creating `SubClassView` instance calls correctly `CustomView.layoutSubviews` but inside this method `SomeProtocol.add` from extension is called instead of `SubClassView.add`. I understand that this is by Swift design but how can achieve that developer of my component without overriding `layoutSubviews` that I prepared for him, overrides only that one `add` method prepared by me for customisation with default implementation that is ready for him if he is not interested in changing it.

```
protocol SomeProtocol: class {
    var property: Int { get set }
    func add() // Method that can be override for custom behaviour
}

extension SomeProtocol where Self: UIView {
    // Default implementation
    func add() {
        property += Int(frame.width)
        print("SomeProtocol.add [property: \(property)]")
    }
}

class CustomView: UIView, SomeProtocol {
    var property: Int = 1

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        print("CustomView.layoutSubviews")
        // Some specific high end code for CustomView
        add()
    }
}

class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, SomeProtocol {
    var property: Int = 2

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        print("CustomCollectionViewCell.layoutSubviews")
        // Some specific high end code for CustomCollectionViewCell
        add()
    }

}

class SubClassView: CustomView { // Class that can implemented by the third party developer for customisation
    // This method will not be called
    func add() {
        property += 10
        print("SubClassView.add [property: \(property)]")
    }
}

let view = SubClassView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
// prints:
// CustomView.layoutSubviews
// SomeProtocol.add [property: 101]
```

Comment: This is almost word-for-word the premise of the example in the latest WWDC talk, Protocol and Value Oriented Programming in UIKit Apps: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/419/ Take a look at their Layout protocol and see if it is the right tool for your case.

Comment: I quickly looked at this talk and seems that we should use composition paradigm. But I have no idea how to use it in my case.

Comment: Can you give a little more detail on the real goal? You've expressed it as an abstract subclassing problem, so it's hard to design a solution that isn't  based on subclassing. It is very possible that "property" and "add" are the wrong starting point.

Comment: @RobNapier Goal is that I want to override some of the base UIKit classes like UIKit to provide basic functionality that could be easy to adjust e.g for overriden pressesBegan method I want to provide default animation. Inside pressesBegan I can check state of the control, change it and depending on the situation call my method pressAnimation() that is implemented in extension to provide default behaviour and should be easy to customize by developer. One problem is that I can't override pressesBegan in extension of the UIView ...

Comment: ... so I need to subclass each UIKit class separately (that's why I tried to use extension to provide default behaviour to avoid duplication of code). Second problem: if developer override my pressesBegan and call super and then provide custom animation, he will add second animation that can cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can add indirect class between yours CustomView and SomeProtocol, lets name it CustomViewBase. This class should inherit UIView and implement SomeProtocol. Now make your class CustomView subclass of CustomViewBase and add to it implementation of add() method and call from it super.add().

Here is code:

```
protocol SomeProtocol: class {
    var property: Int { get set }
    func add() // Method that can be override for custom behaviour
}

extension SomeProtocol where Self: UIView {
    // Default implementation
    func add() {
        property += Int(frame.width)
        print("SomeProtocol.add [property: \(property)]")
    }
}

class CustomViewBase: UIView, SomeProtocol {
    var property: Int = 1
}

class CustomView: CustomViewBase {
    func add() {
        super.add()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        print("CustomView.layoutSubviews 2")
        // Some specific high end code for CustomView
        add()
   }
}

class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, SomeProtocol {
    var property: Int = 2

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        print("CustomCollectionViewCell.layoutSubviews")
        // Some specific high end code for CustomCollectionViewCell
        add()
    }    
}

class SubClassView: CustomView { // Class that can implemented by the     third party developer for customisation
    // This method will not be called
    override func add() {
        property += 10
        print("SubClassView.add [property: \(property)]")
    }
}

let view = SubClassView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's move all the animation stuff into its own thing.

```
struct CustomAnimator {
    var touchesBegan: (UIView) -> Void = { $0.backgroundColor = .red() }
    var touchesEnded: (UIView) -> Void = { $0.backgroundColor = .clear() }
}
```

So this is how we want to animate things. When touches begin, we'll make them red. When touches end, we'll make them clear. This is just an example, and of course can be overridden; these are just default values. This may not be the most convenient data structure for you; you could come up with lots of other ways to store this. But the key is that it's just a struct that animates the thing it is passed. It's not a view itself; there's no subclassing. It's just a value.

So, how can we use this? In cases where it's convenient to subclass, we can use it this way:

```
class CustomDownButton: UIButton {
    var customAnimator: CustomAnimator?

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        customAnimator?.touchesBegan(self)
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        customAnimator?.touchesEnded(self)
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    }
}
```

So if you feel like subclassing your view, you can just assign a `CustomAnimator` onto it and it'll do the thing. But that's not really the interesting case, IMO. The interesting case is when it's *not* convenient to subclass. We want to attach this to a *normal* button.

UIKit already gives us a tool for attaching touch behavior to random views without subclassing them. It's called a gesture recognizer. So let's build one that does our animations:

```
class CustomAnimatorGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer {
    let customAnimator: CustomAnimator

    init(customAnimator: CustomAnimator) {
        self.customAnimator = customAnimator
        super.init(target: nil, action: nil)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        if let view = view {
            customAnimator.touchesBegan(view)
        }
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }

    override func reset() {
        // I'm a bit surprised this isn't in the default impl.
        if self.state == .possible {
            self.state = .failed
        }
        super.reset()
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        if let view = view {
            customAnimator.touchesEnded(view)
        }
        self.reset()
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    }
}
```

It should be pretty obvious how this works. It just calls the animator to modify our view any time touches start or stop. There's a little bit of bookkeeping needed to properly handle the state machine, but it's very straightforward.

There is no step three. Setting this up is trivial:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    customButton.customAnimator = CustomAnimator()
    normalButton.addGestureRecognizer(CustomAnimatorGestureRecognizer(customAnimator: CustomAnimator()))
}
```

Full project on [GitHub](https://github.com/rnapier/TouchDownAnimation).

Comment: You focused on limited case. I had prepared playground with 3 different approaches to the subject https://github.com/nonameplum/Swift-POP-with-Inheritance-problem

Answer (score 0):

I play with this and I came up with 2 different approaches.
(github with playground -> https://github.com/nonameplum/Swift-POP-with-Inheritance-problem)

1. Composition

```
struct BaseFunctionality<T: UIView where T: SomeProtocol> {
    var add: (T) -> Void
    init() {
        add = { (view) in
            view.property += Int(view.frame.width)
            print("BaseFunctionality [property: \(view.property)]")
        }
    }
}

protocol SomeProtocol: class {
    var property: Int { get set }
}

class CustomView: UIView, SomeProtocol {
    var property: Int = 1
    var baseFunc = BaseFunctionality<CustomView>()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        print("CustomView.layoutSubviews")
        // Some specific high end code for CustomView
        baseFunc.add(self)
    }
}

class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, SomeProtocol {
    var property: Int = 2
    var baseFunc = BaseFunctionality<CustomCollectionViewCell>()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        print("CustomCollectionViewCell.layoutSubviews")
        // Some specific high end code for CustomCollectionViewCell
        baseFunc.add(self)
    }

}

class SubClassView: CustomView { // Class that can implemented by the third party developer for customisation

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.baseFunc.add = { (view) in
            view.property -= Int(view.frame.width)
            print("SubClassView [property: \(view.property)]")
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

let view = SubClassView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
```

2. Kind of delegates

```
protocol Functionality: class {
    func add()
}

// Default implementation
extension SomeProtocol where Self: UIView {
    func add() {
        property = -5
        print("Functionality.add [property = \(property)]")
    }
}

protocol SomeProtocol: class {
    var property: Int { get set }
    var delegate: Functionality? { get set }
}

class CustomView: UIView, SomeProtocol {
    var property: Int = 1
    weak var delegate: Functionality?

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        print("CustomView.layoutSubviews")
        // Some specific high end code for CustomView
        if let delegate = delegate {
            delegate.add()
        } else {
            self.add()
        }
    }
}

class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, SomeProtocol {
    var property: Int = 2
    weak var delegate: Functionality?

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        print("CustomCollectionViewCell.layoutSubviews")
        // Some specific high end code for CustomCollectionViewCell
        if let delegate = delegate {
            delegate.add()
        } else {
            self.add()
        }
    }
}

class SubClassView: CustomView { // Class that can implemented by the third party developer for customisation
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.delegate = self
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

extension SubClassView: Functionality {
    func add() {
        property = 5
        print("SubClassView.add [property = \(property)]")
    }
    func doNothing() { print("SubClassView.doNothing [\(property)]") }
}

let view = SubClassView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
```